# Creating polygon feature from list with points using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, coordinates, editing, polygon-creation

I´m trying to build a polygon from a list of coordinates. I have the coordinates in different ways as:

```
pointsfloat
[(583899.8, 8177297.19), (583900.23, 8177262.52), (583896.49, 8177262.47), (583895.96, 8177297.29), (583899.8, 8177297.19)]
```

or

```
coordinates
[583899.8, 8177297.19, 583900.23, 8177262.52, 583896.49, 8177262.47, 583895.96, 8177297.29, 583899.8, 8177297.19]
```

When I try to convert it to a `QgsPoint` I always lose the decimals digits, it's converting the numbers to integer automatically.

How can I generate the polygon feature from those vertices?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the polygon feature so we can evaluate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## QGIS v3.x

You can do it in this way:

```
coords = [(583899.8, 8177297.19), (583900.23, 8177262.52), (583896.49, 8177262.47), (583895.96, 8177297.29), (583899.8, 8177297.19)]   
polygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [[ QgsPointXY( pair[0], pair[1] ) for pair in coords ]] )
```

Now you have a polygon. To see its coordinates:

```
polygon.asWkt(2)
# Prints:
# 'Polygon ((583899.8 8177297.19, 583900.23 8177262.52, 583896.49 8177262.47, 583895.96 8177297.29, 583899.8 8177297.19))'
```

As you see, you aren't losing decimals.

If you want to quickly visualize that polygon, you could use the QuickWKT plugin and paste the WKT representation you just got.

## QGIS v2.x

You can do it in this way:

```
coords = [(583899.8, 8177297.19), (583900.23, 8177262.52), (583896.49, 8177262.47), (583895.96, 8177297.29), (583899.8, 8177297.19)]   
polygon = QgsGeometry.fromPolygon( [[ QgsPoint( pair[0], pair[1] ) for pair in coords ]] )
```

Now you have a polygon. To see its coordinates:

```
polygon.exportToWkt(2)
# Prints:
# u'Polygon ((583899.8 8177297.19, 583900.23 8177262.52, 583896.49 8177262.47, 583895.96 8177297.29, 583899.8 8177297.19))'
```

As you see, you aren't losing decimals.

If you want to quickly visualize that polygon, you could use the QuickWKT plugin and paste the WKT representation you just got.

Comment: Thanks German!!!
I have been trying things like QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([[QgsPoint(x1,y1),QgsPoint(x2,y2), QgsPoint(x3,y3),QgsPoint(x4,y4), QgsPoint(x1,y1)]])
or converting between types and i cant.
Your solution is great.
Regards